# SQL convert datetime to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I want to convert DATETIME to VARCHAR (month/day/year) like this:

```
10/09/2018 12:00:00.000
```

I tried using

```
Convert(VARCHAR(MAX),[Date & Time Added]),121)
```

but it returns

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm
```

I need the `/` format with time, I am Using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that would usually be done in the presentation layer, but if you need to do it in the data layer you can use `FORMAT` ([documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

Syntax is: `FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )`

So in your case *(edited to add AM/PM designation per your comments)*: `FORMAT([Date & Time Added], 'dd/MM/yyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt')`

[Custom date format string options are detailed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: how can I set the AM/PM?

Comment: You can add `tt` to the format string - I've updated the answer to include it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff')
-- 10/09/2018 00:58:52.557
```

Complete list of format specifiers is actually [available in the .NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

---

If `FORMAT` function is unavailable you could simply format in a known format and use string functions to re-arrange the year, month, day and time parts. For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DateStr, 6, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(DateStr, 9, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(DateStr, 1, 4) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(DateStr, 12, 12)
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 126) -- ISO8601 / yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm
) AS CA(DateStr)
-- 10/09/2018 01:12:50.833

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Date, 114)
FROM (
    SELECT GETDATE()
) AS CA(Date)
-- 10/09/2018 01:19:38:463
```

Comment: I take it back.  You matched what the OP wants.  But strange to have month-day-year +1.

Comment: yes! jst had a close look, +1 but if you provide the solution for the SQL Server 2008 version also so it would be better [if you know]